# Youtube Downloader Application

Tags: video, youtube, download, download-manager

I am a computer science student and I want to make an application to automatically download the latest news from youtube and save it on my hdd.
I want to make an application that would download youtube videos that were uploaded on a particular day on a particular channel. I have the following programming skills: C#, JavaScript/Jquery, asp.net, Java.

This is what I want to do :

- Search for the videos on that particular channel on a specific date
- Extract & manipulate header info to generate the get_video token
- Download the videos or feed it to a 3rd party download manager through a txt file

But I am not sure how to do this. Any ideas on how to proceed????
What technologies should I be looking at to make this possible....

Answer (score 2):

Using C#, here is what you may do:

- To search for specific video, you can use Google's YouTube API. There are a few C# samples in the documentation: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet#search_by_keyword. In the "Reference" section, there is also something more specific about filtering by channel.
- I'm not sure, wether the API provides a download functionality: Anyway, you could use this library instead: https://github.com/flagbug/YoutubeExtractor

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

To make Youtube downloader application, you can use the following technologies:

- Reactjs (for front end) . It is based on JavaScript.
- 'react-player' node module for embedding Youtube.
- Google's Youtube API to get the list of videos based on the search.
- "ReadableStream" object of JavaScript for downloading the stream and video files. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API/Using_readable_streams)
- Nodejs for back-end.

Example of a Youtube downloader is YTDownload. You can contact the website or youtube developer for more details.